# Cancelling iOS In-App-Purchase auto renew subscription within the app

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit, in-app-subscription

The users can cancel the subscribed in-app-purchase by going to iOS settings. But I'm not seeing a way to allow the users to cancel the subscription from the app using SKStoreKit. Is there a way to allow the users to do so?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible, you can just link to the manage subscriptions in the settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an API to cancel an auto-renewable subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575112/is-there-an-api-to-cancel-an-auto-renewable-subscription)