# Does In-App Purchase has payment methods same as stripe?

Tags: ios, react-native, stripe-payments, in-app-purchase, stripes

I'm currently stuck with some In-App Purchase (IAP) problems.
In my project, user has an account using both web application and mobile app.
I'm using Stripe on web and IAP on mobile to handle user's payment methods and I have to handle the user's subscription on both platform.
My questions are:

1. When user cancel subscription on web using Stripe, can I handle the event on Stripe to cancel the subscription on IAP?
2. I find out that user cannot cancel subscription within the App, user have to cancel it in Iphone Settings. Can I handle the event when user cancel subscription on IAP in order to cancel subscription on Stripe?
3. When user change subscription on web (ex: monthly to yearly) by using Stripe, how can I handle the event in order to cancel subscription on the Iphone by using IAP?
4. Do IAP has the schedule payment same as Stripe? and when user are using auto-renewable subscription on IAP, can I bring it to a schedule in order to change subscription in the future like Stripe do?
   Thanks in advance!

I just started to research on IAP for IOS and I'm about to using react-native-iap to solve it

Answer (score 0):

1. When user cancel subscription on web using Stripe, can I handle the event on Stripe to cancel the subscription on IAP?
2. When user change subscription on web (ex: monthly to yearly) by using Stripe, how can I handle the event in order to cancel subscription on the Iphone by using IAP?

> i don't think there is any way that you can cancel/update the IAP
> subscription without iPhone settings or app. [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5680616/9608873)

2. I find out that user cannot cancel subscription within the App, user have to cancel it in Iphone Settings. Can I handle the event when user cancel subscription on IAP in order to cancel subscription on Stripe?

> when user cancel the subscription or upgrade/downgrade your backend will get web-hook which you will provide in AppStoreConnect under app information.